# How do I calculate Hours between dates with a 8-hour work day and accounting for weekends? (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, date, calculation

I need some help calculating hours worked between two dates, but with an 8-hour work day. I also need to adjust for weekends so I don't say someone took longer then they actually did. I am using VB.net

For example, date1 is `1/23/2020 9:00:00 AM`, the start date, and date2 is `1/27/2020 1:30:00 PM`, the finish time.

If I run this code:

```
Dim hours As double = DateDiff(DateInterval.hour, date1, date2)
```

it would give me the total hours, but would include weekends and not filter it for an 8 hour day.

How can I filter out workday times and weekends? Any help in refining this would be appreciated

Comment: You include time in your start date and end date, but your assumption is that the days in-between are always 8hrs?

Comment: @Anu6is Yes, all in between days not given a specific hour will be assigned as 8 hours. only that day (end or start) will start the calculation from the hour provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option

```vb
'Get all days between the start date and the end date
Dim midDays As Date() = Enumerable.Range(0, endDate.Subtract(startDate.AddDays(1)).Days).Select(Function(offset) startDate.AddDays(offset)).ToArray
'Filter out any weekend days
Dim weekdays As Date() = midDays.Where(Function(day) day.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso day.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToArray
'Assume all days are a full 8 hours
Dim hoursWorked As Decimal = weekdays.Count * 8
```

This essentially creates a list of all days between the start and end date. Remove weekends from the list and calculates 8 hours for each remaining day.

Of course you would then add the hours from the first and last day to the total.

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop

```
    Dim td As DateTime
    If endDate < startDate Then
        'switch
        td = endDate
        endDate = startDate
        startDate = td
    End If
    Dim hours As Integer = 0
    td = startDate
    While td < endDate
        If td.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso td.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
            hours += 8
        End If
        td = td.AddDays(1)
    End While
```